# How to pass javascript variable to php in html? (wikipedia parsing)

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, parsing

Hi I'm trying to pass a javascript variable called $url to a function in php all located in the same html file. The logic here is that there is a text box and the user inputs a species and we call the wikipedia api to check if the input has a wikipedia page if it does I parse the page and bring the species info up, everything works independently 100% but I cant seem to connect them. However I cant get javascript to pass the url to the php function below. and innerHTML the php function with the url which is suppose to render the parsed species info. The error I get is that from the get go I just get the php function spit out with nothing.

```
Enter a species here : [text box here]
find('table.infobox'); foreach($html->find('img') as $element) { $image[]= $element; } Print $image[1]; $data = array(); foreach($table[0]->find('tr') as $row) { $td = $row->find('> td'); if (count($td) == 2) { $name = $td[0]->innertext; $td = $td[1]->find('a'); $text = $td[0]->innertext; $data[$name] = $text; } } print ""; foreach($data as $value => $before ) { print ""; } print "
$value  $before
"; } ?>
```

Here is my attempt so far, I call the javascript and check if a link is found and call the parse function to innerthml out in the result div

```
<?php
//call the javascript 
//if link found
//send ajax url variable to php function
//ajax call the function innerhtml in the result div



//We check if we have the param within the page call
$theDeletenode = false;
if(isset($_POST['deletenode']))
    $theDeletenode = $_POST['deletenode'];

if($theDeletenode)
{
    //The param 'deletenode' is given, so we juste have to call the php function "parse", to return the value
    parse($theDeletenode);
}else
{
    // No parametre, so we echo the javascript, and the form (without the quote and \n, it's much better)
?>
```

Here is the start of my html, the text box is connected to javascript which called the wikipedia api to check if the input has a wikipedia page.

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 // create and return an  XMLHttpRequest object
 function createRequest() {
    var ajaxRequest;  // the xmlrequest object
   try{
       // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
                }
            }
        }
    return ajaxRequest;
}; // end of createRequest

var spellcheck =  function(data){
    var found=false;var url=''; 
    var text=data[0];
   if(text!=document.getElementById('spellcheckinput').value) return;
      for(i=0;i<data[1].length;i++)
          {
          if(text.toLowerCase()==data[1][i].toLowerCase())
              {found=true;
              url='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'+text;
              document.getElementById('spellcheckresult').innerHTML='<b style=\"color:green\">Correct</b> - <a target=\"_top\" href=\"'+url+'\">link</a>';
              }
          }
      if(!found)
        document.getElementById('spellcheckresult').innerHTML='<b style=\"color:red\">Incorrect</b>';
        };


var requestone = createRequest();

var getjs=   function(value)
{
    if(!value) return;
    var url='http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search='+value+'&format=json&callback=spellcheck'; // this is the variable I want to pass
    document.getElementById('spellcheckresult').innerHTML='Checking ...';
    var elem=document.createElement('script');
    elem.setAttribute('src',url);
    elem.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(elem);

    // Ajax call to this page, this time with the 'deletenode' parameter
    var vars = "url=" + encodeURIComponent(url);
    requestone.open("POST", "parser.php", true); // parser.php : the name of this current page
    requestone.onreadystatechange = handleRequest;  // function to handle the response
    requestone.send(vars);

};      

  function handleRequest()
  {
    //here we handle the php page response by echoing de result of the php page (normally the result of the parse function) 
    try{
        if(requestone.readyState == 4 && requestone.status == 200)
          document.getElementById('resultdiv').innerHTML= requestone.responseText;
    } catch (e) {
        //Wrong server answer...
    }
  }; 
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="#" method="get" onsubmit="return false">
<p>Enter a species here : <input id="spellcheckinput" onkeyup="getjs (this.value);" type="text">
 <span id="spellcheckresult"></span></p>
</form>
<div id=resultdiv></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my parse function which recieves a variable called url which is the validated wikipedia page and then it parses it for species info, this tested and it works but I cant get it to innerhtml this function along with the validated wikipedia url.

```
<?php 
}
function parse($url){
print $url;
$html = file_get_html('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beaver');
$table = $html->find('table.infobox');


foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
{
       $image[]= $element;     
}
Print $image[1];

$data = array();
foreach($table[0]->find('tr') as $row)
{    
    $td = $row->find('> td');
    if (count($td) == 2)
    {
        $name = $td[0]->innertext;
        $td = $td[1]->find('a');
$text = $td[0]->innertext;
        $data[$name] = $text;

    }
}
print "<table class='infobox' style='text-align: left; width: 200px; font-size: 100%'>";
foreach($data as $value => $before )
{

print "<tr><td>$value</td><td>$before</td></tr>";
}
print "</table>";

 }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has many related answers [1](https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/php-javascript-variable-value-transfer.16822/)[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines)[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191124/send-javascript-variable-to-php-variable)[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

If it helps, here is some JavaScript:

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
var input = document.createElement("input");
form.method="{post/get}";
form.action="{page}";
input.name="{name}";
input.value="{value}";
form.appendChild(input);
form.submit();
```