# comparing rgb color code in php

Tags: javascript, php

Following is my code :

```
<div id="accept" style="background-color:#83CC3F;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function accept1() {
return document.getElementById('accept').style.backgroundColor;
}
 </script>
<?php
$js=<<<EOF
<script type="text/javascript" >
document.write(accept1());
 </script>
EOF;
echo $js;
if($js == "rgb(131, 204, 63)") //rgb(131, 204, 63) rgb equivalent of hex code #83CC3F
{
echo "yes"; 
}
?>
```

Above code doesn't return "yes" whereas $js=rgb(131, 204, 63) ,
Please solve my problem

Comment: $js is `<script type="text/javascript" >
document.write(accept1());
 </script>` so it isn't `rgb(131, 204, 63)`

Comment: use AJAX for sending javascipt value to php script

Comment: but when i print $js it prints rgb(131, 204, 63)

Comment: @DushyantJoshi above code is just demo code i will later use ajax when i implement above code in my project,my problem is in comparision of "if statement" which return false rather than true

Comment: @user47288, You will get proper value when you will be using AJAX. The above code is wrong. See my answer

Comment: thank you @DushyantJoshi for your ans,i have one more ques that "how to get css property(internal css) of an element in javascript?"

Comment: @user47288, check here http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html. If you do not understand ask a different question with your trials so that others or I can answer it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't take var like this in php..

```
$js=<<<EOF
<script type="text/javascript" >
document.write(accept1());
 </script>
```

because php is server side language ..
and javascript is client side.

For this you have to use ajax ,get and post methods

**UPDATE1:**

It's always always  important to remember that `Javascript` executes on the clients browser, & `PHP` executes on the server. So `$js` has no idea what

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
document.write(accept1());
 </script>
```

will be, **because that won't execute until it reaches the viewers browser. & just as well, once the viewers browser gets it, `PHP` is done executing, so it can't hand the output off**.

**UPDATE2**: If you do the following it will echo yes.

```
if($js == '<script type="text/javascript" >document.write(accept1());</script>'); //rgb(131, 204, 63) rgb equivalent of hex code #83CC3F
{
echo "yes"; 
}
```

This is because PHP variable `$js` still has `<script type="text/javascript" >document.write(accept1());</script>` value set.

Comment: but when i print $js it prints rgb(131, 204, 63) why?

Comment: Carefully read my update in the answer(also in bold). It clearly resolves your doubt.

Comment: See the Jordan Answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191124/send-javascript-variable-to-php-variable

Answer (score 0):

Your must check this codes in js, but PHP not render the content and not get color from html element.

For checking RGB by eq to HEX, you can convert each part RGB to DEC and concatenation this string, and after check eq.

For example RGB(10, 20, 30):

`DECTOHEX(10) . DECTOHEX(20) . DECTOHEX(30) == '#0A141E'`