# Put JavaScript variable value as the argument of PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, argument-passing

I have this function in my PHP code.

```
<?php
 $user = get_user_by_id($user_id);
?>
```

And I also have a JavaScript code on the same page. 
The JavaScript generates some value to a JS variable.

What I need to do is, using that JavaScript variable value as the argument of the above PHP function.

So, what's the simplest method for achieving this..?

Comment: `server side` <-- is here and if you go waaaaaay over here you will finally find -->`client side`; And in between there is a big gab!

Comment: Pass the javascript code to a php function with ajax(drumrolls)

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191124/send-javascript-variable-to-php-variable

Comment: Mmm so, will have to find another way. Anyway, thanks.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not quiet possible. You can't use client side variables (ECMA Script) inside your server side scripts (PHP). You may be able to achieve this by creating a web service and passing the variables using XHTTP Requests (AJAX) or reload the page using ECMA Script passing the value as a parameter and using it server side.

I don't know what exactly you are trying to do so I can't give you a definitive answer to this.

Comment: Thanks.. That'll be too complicated for this. Will have to start over and find another way for doing that. Thanks for the info...