# why my sql query in php not working while I am trying to add the php variable into sql query?

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I am trying to integrate the php and javascript. I send the javascript variable into php variable. And printed it out in the browser using `echo` command. It outputs the exact same result that I am expecting. I write following command;

```
<script>
    var p1 ='Lohuti'
</script>
<?php
            $p1="<script>document.write(p1);</script>";
            $db_connection = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres password=admin");
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM public.flood WHERE jamoat= '".$p1."'";
            echo $sql;
            $result = pg_query($db_connection, $sql);
            while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
               $row[0]
            }
?>
```

The `echo $sql` prints outs `SELECT * FROM public.flood WHERE jamoat= 'Lohuti'`. But this query unable to fetch the data from a database. If I just replace the php variable `$p1` with the name `Lohuti`, It works fine, I can fetch the data. In my case, I am planning to add the dynamic javascript variable into php variable and query the required result. Is there any solution to this type of problem?

Comment: Your issue is that `$p1` is not actually `Lohuti`, that's just what you see when you render `<script>document.write(p1);</script>` in a  browser. See the duplicates for methods to pass a JS variable to a PHP script.

Comment: I am following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24950211/9354344) this answer. What is the problem with this answer?

Comment: See ToolmakerSteve's comment to that answer. That answer is incorrect.

Comment: Do you have any good idea to pass the dyanamic javascript variable to php variable? I want less code method. Please suggest me

Comment: Sorry but there aren't any easy ways, you have to either use a request, by changing location (`http://url/p1=Lohuti`) or submitting a form with e.g. `<input type="hidden" value="Lohuti" name="p1">` or using an ajax request to pass the variable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8191134 this solution works for me. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution.