# How do I determine if a HTML-form answer is correct (calling PHP via $.post), without revealing the answer?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I'm working on a fill-in-the-blank quiz ([current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvsH1.jpg)).  In my `index.php`, I want to verify that the user `input` is the correct answer (as in, it matches what's in my MySQL server).

I can verify the answer is correct by `<?php echo ... ?>`-ing the answer, but this results in the answer being in the in the html file, which has the drawback of allowing cheating.

I gather from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8191134/2842962), that I need to use something like `$.post('file.php', {variable: variableToSend});`, so I attempt to do that:

```
<script>
    function process_guess() {
        var input = [...snip...];

        [...snip...]

        var is_correct = $.post('process_answer.php', {guess: input});

        [...snip...]

        if(is_correct == 1) {
            [...snip...]
        }
        else {
            [...snip...]
        }
    }
</script>
```

The above Javascript function is called from a html form elsewhere in my `index.php`; I can used `console.log` to verify that the `input` variable above is the actual user input.  However, judging from `console.log`, the way I'm using `$.post` is totally wrong, but I'm not sure what the correct syntax is.

In `process_answer.php` I have:

```
<?php
    if($_POST['guess'] == $problem_data["answer"]) echo "1";
    else echo "0"; 
?>
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

**Question**: How do I determine if a HTML-form answer is correct (calling PHP via $.post), without revealing the answer?

Comment: So post the answer to the server and have the server check to see if it is right. Have the server return a boolean

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do.  I'm just not succeeding.

Comment: I think what you might need to do is to `json_decode` the response in the PHP before you check since you are passing a JSON object in the `$.post`

Comment: `$.post('process_answer.php', {guess: input}).done(function(xxx) {
    console.log(xxx);
  });`

Comment: @aljx0409 OP is not posting JSON. That is how jQuery posts `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're approach is good. The ajax call is a good way to do it.

In Javascript, according to [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), you just have to wait for a server response. But you have to notice that is asynchronous (so the code below, will probably be executed before your callback). I propose something like that.

```
$.post('process_answer.php', {guess: input})
  .done(function( data ) {
    // Execute your logic inside the request callback
    if(data) {
        [...snip...]
    }
    else {
        [...snip...]
    }
  }
);
```

And in your php, I suggest to exit the script or simply return a value

```
<?php
// return a json encoded boolean
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($_POST['guess'] == $problem_data["answer"]);die;
?>
```

EDIT after Phil's comment :

Phil is right, I've updated my example.

Comment: The PHP needs an `echo`, not a `return`. I would also add `header('Content-type: application/json')` and `json_encode()` the response

Comment: @Phil You're right, after a quick test, the return isn't sufficient. Bad habit from using frameworks :)